# In ReactNative, which Async Await method is better in these two and why?

Tags: react-native, async-await, es6-promise

`verifyUser` which awaits `verifyUserSignInSuccess` which awaits `userSnapshot` which awaits `user`

Here in these two functions, which will be more effective in terms of correctness, memory, time for ReactNative app :

```
export function verifyUser() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(verifyUserSignInRequest());
    try {
      const user = await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged();

        if (user) {
          let userRef = "/user/" + user.uid;
          const userSnapshot = await firebase
            .database()
            .ref(userRef)
            .once("value");
          dispatch(verifyUserSignInSuccess(userSnapshot.val()));
        } else {
          dispatch(verifyUserSignInFailure(USER_NOT_SIGNED_IN));
        }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(verifyUserSignInFailure(e.message));
    }
  };
}
```

Or the Nested Async Await :

```
export function verifyUser() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(verifyUserSignInRequest());
    try {
      await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        if (user) {
          let userRef = "/user/" + user.uid;
          await firebase
            .database()
            .ref(userRef)
            .once("value")
            .then( () => {
              dispatch(verifyUserSignInSuccess(userSnapshot.val()));
            });
        } else {
          dispatch(verifyUserSignInFailure(USER_NOT_SIGNED_IN));
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(verifyUserSignInFailure(e.message));
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I think the first option is better, because easier to read. I would not use async/await, but Promise instead. Second one is a mix of async/await promise which makes it a little bit harder to read. I my opinion, I would chain Promise to have it clean and nice :)

Comment: The first is more readable, outdent the `if (user) / else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged), the `onAuthStateChanged()` function returns

> The unsubscribe function for the observer.

So you can just:

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) {
    // handle it for changes signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token expiry or password change 
});
```

And then:

`unsubscribe();` for registering the for observer.

`onAuthStateChanged` is a Observer which calls  the observer when users were signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token expiry or password change . so the second one is the best solution . every login or change .

```
` let userRef = "/user/" + user.uid;
          await firebase
            .database()
            .ref(userRef)
            .once("value")
            .then( () => {
              dispatch(verifyUserSignInSuccess(userSnapshot.val()));
            });
        } else {
          dispatch(verifyUserSignInFailure(USER_NOT_SIGNED_IN));
        }`
```

that is correct to cross check is user is valid or not .i dont't thinks there is memory comparison is required.

Answer (score 2):

Time - Since all your async functions need to run one after the other whichever method u use async/await or promise chaining or a mix up of both will take same time only.

Correctness - Both are correct logically and will work the same. But async/await is the latest addition to JS to solve the problem of promise chaining. Promise chaining leaves the code hard to read. Better U stick to async/await.For situations where u need to run two async functions parallelly, use `await Promise.all()` etc. In the end, it's your personal preference.

Memory? - I have no idea on that

Read this book its free on github which contains details on promises, async functions, async/await etc.
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS